# Как, не зная индекс, заменить произвольные элементы списка?

Tags: python, list

Одна из задач на обучающем курсе. Дан список:

```
lst = ['Anthony', 'is', 'complete', 'bastard.]
```

Требуется заменить элементы 'bastard.' на 'badass.' и вывести всё это дело. Конечно, на ум приходит что-то вроде:

```
lst[3] = 'badass'
print(lst)
```

Но что делать в том случае, если мне неизвестен индекс необходимой строки? Можно ли осуществить замену необходимых строк, если известно лишь их содержание?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать это с помощью метода `index`, он возвращает индекс по указаному значению

То есть примерно так:

```
lst = ['Anthony', 'is', 'complete', 'bastard']
lst[lst.index('bastard')] = 'new_value'
```

В итоге у нас будет новый список с изменённым значением

[image: Показ измененного списка]

Comment: Проблема будет, если такого слова нет или если их несколько штук в списке.

Answer (score 2):

Пройти по массиву целиком

```
lst = ['Anthony', 'is', 'complete', 'bastard']
lst = list(map(lambda x: 'badass' if x=='bastard' else x, lst ))
print(lst)
```

или поискать индексы

```
lst = ['Anthony', 'is', 'complete', 'bastard']
index = 0
while True:
    try:
        index = lst.index('bastard', index)
    except ValueError:
        break
    lst[index] = 'badass'
print(lst)
```

или списковые включение

```
lst = ['Anthony', 'is', 'complete', 'bastard']
lst = [('badass' if x=='bastard' else x) for x in lst ]
print(lst)
```

Comment: Зачем так сложно `list(map(lambda`, если можно просто списковое включение написать с тем же тернарным `if`-ом внутри? )

Comment: @CrazyElf это уже третий способ

Comment: Да нет, это практически тот же способ, только проще записанный. Список генерится заново, слово выбирается тернарным оператором, идёт перебор списка - всё тоже самое, только без излишеств. Ну да ладно.

Comment: @CrazyElf добавил в ответ ;) семанитика не как у "функционального" map - поэтому это отдельный способ. я не люблю тринарные операторы вкладывать в тренарные операторы...

Answer (score 0):

```
def replace(iterable, old, new, count=-1):
    if not isinstance(count, int):
        type_name = count.__class__.__name__
        msg = f'integer argument expected, got {type_name}'
        raise TypeError(msg)
    
    iterable = iter(iterable)
    for el in iterable:
        if count == 0:
            break
        
        if el == old:
            count -= 1
            yield new
        else:
            yield el
    
    yield from iterable
```